# jQuery selected name

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

If Tom is selected from the drop down box, how do I get the name and not the value using jQuery so that the resulting output would be Tom?

```
<select id="emp" >
  <option value=1>Tom</option>
  <option value=12>Harold</option>e 
  <option value=32>Jenny</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var res = $('#emp :selected').text();
```

This gets the element with [the ID](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) `emp`, then gets [the descendant element](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) that is [`:selected`](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/), finally returns [the `.tex()` content](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Here's a plain javascript version:

```
var el = document.getElementById('emp');

var res = el.options[el.selectedIndex].text;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#emp option:selected').text();
```